# Proof of Taylor expansion in multiple variables

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, taylor-expansion

Given a smooth function $f:\mathbb R^n\rightarrow \mathbb R$, can I expand it at $a\in \mathbb R^n$so that

> $f(x)=f(a)+\sum(x_i-a)g_i(x)$ where $g_i$ are smooth functions with $g_i(a)=\frac {\partial f}{\partial x_i}(a)$?

If so, I would like to see some reference for(or direct here) the proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The result you wrote is true : it is called *Hadamard's Lemma*, but it is not truly a Taylor expansion of $f$ in a neighbourhood of $0$. Actually, the proof of your result relies heavily on the Taylor formula with integral rest. See [the Wikipedia page of the Hadamard's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_lemma) for more details on the proof.

If you are looking for "true" Taylor formulas in case of functions in multiple variables, you should check [this Wikipedia page about them](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor_series) which will contain the formulas. As for how you can prove them, I can't think of an english reference as of now, but the usual way of proving them relies on the following principle :

Take a function $f : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$, and also $a,x$ $\in \mathbb{R}^n$ (with $a$ the point where you're looking for a Taylor expansion). Then define $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ with $g(t) = f(a + t(x-a))$, and write down Taylor's formula for $g$ (where any version would work - just pay attention to the Taylor Lagrange one, you can find more information about why by searching on Google about the mean value theorem in multiples variables).

I guess I went a bit overboard with this answer, and not that precise. I hope it helped though, and feel free to ask any question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can expand $f:\mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ in the way posted because $\mathbb{R}^n$ is a neighborhood of the point $a$.

> If so, I would like to see some reference for(or direct here) the proof.

A proof can be found in Loring Tu's *An Introduction to Manifolds* (Second Edition) on page no.6.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/1299092)

Comment: @JohnB Why not? The op asks for a reference.